# how to use spring boot admin in docker swarm

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Spring boot admin works fine if I run the spring boot app as an individual container under the same network.

How do I make it work for stack deployment or in swarm mode?

I tried creating a compose file with spring boot app and spring boot admin and changed the admin URL on app to `localhost:8080`(even tried with `admin:8080`, I know this will not work because the container name is no longer admin and compose creates a random name and `container_name` option is not supported in swarm mode), both admin and app started fine expect client is not registering with server. The problem will be the `localhost:8080`.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `spring.boot.admin.client.prefer-ip=true` and the client will use the ip and not hostname in url. Also ensure clients can reach the server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `prefer-ip` to true does not work either. The internal IP can change with each deployment.